# How to sort or rearrange numbers from multiple column into multiple row [fixed into 4 columns]?

Tags: linux, perl, awk, sed

I have 1 text file, which is test1.txt.

text1.txt contain as following:

Input:

```
##[A1] [B1] [T1]  [V1] [T2]  [V2] [T3]  [V3] [T4]  [V4]## --> headers
    1  1000    0   100   10   200   20   300   30   400
              40   500   50   600   60   700   70   800
       1010    0   101   10   201   20   301   30   401
              40   501   50   601  
    2  1000    0   110   15   210   25   310   35   410
              45   510   55   610   65   710
       1010    0   150   10   250   20   350   30   450
              40   550
```

Condition:
A1 and B1 -> for each A1 + (B1 + [Tn + Vn]) 
A1 should be in 1 column.
B1 should be in 1 column.
T1,T2,T3 and T4 should be in 1 column.
V1,V2,V3 and V4 should be in 1 column.

How do I sort it become like below?

Desire Output:

```
##   A1    B1   Tn    Vn ## --> headers

      1  1000    0   100
                10   200
                20   300
                30   400
                40   500
                50   600
                60   700
                70   800
         1010    0   101
                10   201
                20   301
                30   401
                40   501
                50   601
      2  1000    0   110
                15   210
                25   310
                35   410
                45   510
                55   610
                65   710
         1010    0   150
                10   250
                20   350
                30   450
                40   550
```

Here is my current code:

 First Attempt:

 Input

```
cat test1.txt | awk ' { a=$1 b=$2 } { for(i=1; i<=5; i=i+1) { t=substr($0,11+i*10,5) v=substr($0,16+i*10,5) if( t ~ /^\ +[0-9]+$/ || t ~ /^[0-9]+$/ || t ~ /^\ +[0-9]+\ +$/ ){ printf "%7s %7d %8d %8d \n",a,b,t,v } }}' | less
```

Output:

```
      1    1000      400        0 
     40     500      800        0 
   1010       0      401        0 
      2    1000      410        0 
   1010       0      450        0
```

I'm trying using simple awk command, but still can't get the result.
Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks,

Am

Comment: Also, do you tags 'linux, perl, awk, sed` mean it doesn't which is used? You will only need one for the solution.

Comment: Any text processing languages can be used, but prefer in awk, sed, perl that commonly used in Linux terminal.

Comment: Do all rows have consistent delimiters, and what are they?  So, the second raw after the header (which has no `1 1000`), does it have two empty fields delimited with the same thing as the first two fields in the first row?

Comment: yes can have consistent delimiters like whitespaces, as long it output only 4 columns.

Comment: OK, but what does the input file have? Is it tab delimited? Or just "some" number of spaces between numbers?

Comment: some number of spaces between numbers, yep correct

Comment: What makes this tricky is identifying when you've got a 'first row' (with 1:1000 for example in columns 1 and 2) versus a second row (with no value in columns 1 or 2) or a third row (where you've no value in column 1).  The third row may be easiest; the number of values is odd.  Is it safe to assume that 10 fields means a 'first row'?  Or could you have just 1, 2 or 3 pairs (after the key) on a first row?

Comment: A1, B1, Tn and Vn is a headers. A1 have different B1 and B1 consist of different Tn and Vn.

Comment: Your input format is unclear. How do you identify columns? Is the first line really there? What is its format?

Comment: The input file have fixed 10 columns and many rows.
These 10 columns are A1,B1,T1,V1,T2,V2,T3,V3,T4,V4. Each A1 can consist of a couple of rows that have different B1 and Tn and Vn.
Let assume A1 is group, B1 is the name of student, T is time taken and V is velocities. For each group, there are some student, and each student have their own time taken and velocities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather tricky problem that can be handled a number of ways. Whether `bash`, `perl` or `awk`, you will need to handle to number of fields in some semi-generic way instead of just hardcoding values for your example.

Using bash, so long as you can rely on an even-number of fields in all lines (except for the lines with the sole initial value (e.g. `1010`), you can accommodate the number of fields is a reasonably generic way. For the lines with `1, 2`, etc.. you know your initial output will contain `4-fields`. For lines with `1010`, etc.. you know the output will contain an initial `3-fields`. For the remaining values you are simply outputting *pairs*.

The tricky part is handling the *alignment*. Here is where `printf` which allows you to set the *field-width* with a parameter using the form `"%*s"` where the conversion specifier expects the next parameter to be an `integer` value specifying the *field-width* followed by a parameter for the string conversion itself. It takes a little gymnastics, but you could do something like the following in bash itself:

**(note: edit to match your output header format)**

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i nfields wd=6     ## total no. fields, printf field-width modifier

while read -r line; do      ## read each line  (preserve for header line)
    arr=($line)             ## separate into array
    first=${arr[0]}         ## check for '#' in first line for header
    if [ "${first:0:1}" = '#' ]; then
        nfields=$((${#arr[@]} - 2))     ## no. fields in header
        printf "##   A1    B1   Tn    Vn ## --> headers\n"  ## new header
        continue
    fi
    fields=${#arr[@]}                   ## fields in line
    case "$fields" in
        $nfields )                      ## fields -eq nfiles?
            cnt=4                       ## handle 1st 4 values in line
            printf " "
            for ((i=0; i < cnt; i++)); do
                if [ "$i" -eq '2' ]; then
                    printf "%*s" "5" "${arr[i]}"
                else
                    printf "%*s" "$wd" "${arr[i]}"
                fi
            done
            echo
            for ((i = cnt; i < $fields; i += 2)); do    ## handle rest
                printf "%*s%*s%*s\n" "$((2*wd))" " " "$wd" "${arr[i]}" "$wd" "${arr[$((i+1))]}"
            done
            ;;
        $((nfields - 1)) )              ## one less than nfields
            cnt=3                       ## handle 1st 3 values
            printf " %*s%*s" "$wd" " "
            for ((i=0; i < cnt; i++)); do
                if [ "$i" -eq '1' ]; then
                    printf "%*s" "5" "${arr[i]}"
                else
                    printf "%*s" "$wd" "${arr[i]}"
                fi
            done
            echo
            for ((i = cnt; i < $fields; i += 2)); do    ## handle rest
                if [ "$i" -eq '0' ]; then
                    printf "%*s%*s%*s\n" "$((wd+1))" " " "$wd" "${arr[i]}" "$wd" "${arr[$((i+1))]}"
                else
                    printf "%*s%*s%*s\n" "$((2*wd))" " " "$wd" "${arr[i]}" "$wd" "${arr[$((i+1))]}"
                fi
            done
            ;;
        * )     ## all other lines format as pairs
            for ((i = 0; i < $fields; i += 2)); do
                printf "%*s%*s%*s\n" "$((2*wd))" " " "$wd" "${arr[i]}" "$wd" "${arr[$((i+1))]}"
            done
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Rather than reading from a file, just use redirection to redirect the input file to your script (if you want to just provide a filename, then redirect the file to feed the output `while read...` loop)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash text1format.sh <dat/text1.txt
##   A1    B1   Tn    Vn ## --> headers
      1  1000    0   100
                10   200
                20   300
                30   400
                40   500
                50   600
                60   700
                70   800
         1010    0   101
                10   201
                20   301
                30   401
                40   501
                50   601
      2  1000    0   110
                15   210
                25   310
                35   410
                45   510
                55   610
                65   710
         1010    0   150
                10   250
                20   350
                30   450
                40   550
```

As between `awk` and `bash`, `awk` will generally be faster, but here with formatted output, it may be closer than usual. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for your advice and answer. We will try these code to see whether it can solve the real problem.

Comment: This gonna take some time. I will let you know once I have successfully crack it.

Comment: Hi David. This script works very well on the real problem. I just need to modified these parameters and conditions. Thank you very much for helping me on this problem.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped. There is very little you can't do with bash. It's not always the fastest horse in the stable, but for all but billion record files, it is generally fast enough. But as with my earlier comment, when you are simply grabbing columns and manipulating the values without the same formatting I/O calls, it is generally faster and can readily handle large files. `sed` is more a stream-editor rather than a formatting utility. @JonathanLeffler answer uses `sed` to add `'|'` between the fields to make it easier on `awk` to parse. That is another good approach.

Comment: *"There is very little you can't do with bash"* There is also very little that you *should* do with it. It is also possible to persuade a dog to walk on its hind legs. This is an abomination.

Comment: Please don't pressure people to select an answer unless it really seems that they have overlooked it. 48 hours is a reasonable period for assessment.

Comment: Don't do this. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons why. wrt the statment at the end `As between awk and bash, awk will generally be faster, but here with formatted output, it may be closer than usual` - no, that shell script will be **several** orders of magnitude slower than an awk script for this task. For a moderately large file we're literally talking hours vs seconds.

Comment: @EdMorton - the answer you cite actually supports the propriety of what I have done. There are no utilities called within a loop (the "Performance" penalty), there are no "pipes" ("Conceptual") and the ("Readability") is arguable between it and sed/awk. Further, the cited answer was for POSIX shell, not bash.

Comment: @Borodin - I didn't pressure anyone to come back within any timeframe - did I? No. The rash of unanswered questions that bob around of ever in that state is something to be avoided. We even have a whole section on "What to do when someone answers my question" that I generally cite.

Comment: You call the `read` and `echo` utilities within the loop. The only mention of bash in my comment was your statement which I quoted. You are correct, people can always debate readability but your shell script is 3-4 times longer than [my awk script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51154942/1745001) and contains several non-obvious array manipulation constructs plus nested conditionals within loops within switches within other loops, repeated/redundant code, etc. so I personally don't see any argument for the shell script being clearer than the awk script in this particular case but YMMV I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike what is stated elsewhere, there's nothing tricky about this at all, you're just using fixed width fields in your input instead of char/string separated fields.

With GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS to handle fixed width fields it really couldn't be much simpler:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    # define the width of the input and output fields
    FIELDWIDTHS = "2 4 5 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6 99"
    ofmt = "%2s%5s%6s%5s%6s%s\n"
}
{
    # strip leading/trailing blanks and square brackets from every field
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
         gsub(/^[[\s]+|[]\s]+$/,"",$i)
    }
}
NR==1 {
    # print the header line
    printf ofmt, $1, $2, $3, "Tn", "Vn", " "$NF
    next
}
{
    # print every other line
    for (i=4; i<NF; i+=2) {
        printf ofmt, $1, $2, $3, $i, $(i+1), ""
        $1 = $2 = $3 = ""
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
##   A1    B1   Tn    Vn ## --> headers
      1  1000    0   100
                10   200
                20   300
                30   400
                40   500
                50   600
                60   700
                70   800
         1010    0   101
                10   201
                20   301
                30   401
                40   501
                50   601
      2  1000    0   110
                15   210
                25   310
                35   410
                45   510
                55   610
                65   710
         1010    0   150
                10   250
                20   350
                30   450
                40   550
```

With other awks you'd use a `while() { substr() }` loop instead of `FIELDWIDTHS` so it'd be a couple more lines of code but still trivial.

The above will be orders of magnitude faster than an equivalent shell script. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for your help and advise. These code looks really good and useful. I have used it on my real sample and it goes well.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't easy because it is hard to identify when you have the different styles of row — those with values in both column 1 and column 2, those with no value in column 1 and a value in column 2, and those no value in column 1 or 2.  A first step is to make this easier — `sed` to the rescue:

```
$ sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}$//
s/^....../&|/
s/|....../&|/
:a
s/|\(  *[0-9][0-9]* \)\( *[^|]\)/|\1|\2/
t a' data
    1 | 1000 |   0 |  100 |  10 |  200 |  20 |  300 |  30 |  400
      |      |  40 |  500 |  50 |  600 |  60 |  700 |  70 |  800
      | 1010 |   0 |  101 |  10 |  201 |  20 |  301 |  30 |  401
      |      |  40 |  501 |  50 |  601
    2 | 1000 |   0 |  110 |  15 |  210 |  25 |  310 |  35 |  410
      |      |  45 |  510 |  55 |  610 |  65 |  710
      | 1010 |   0 |  150 |  10 |  250 |  20 |  350 |  30 |  450
      |      |  40 |  550
$
```

The first line removes any trailing white space, to avoid confusion. The next two expressions handle the fixed-width columns 1 and 2 (6 characters each). The next line creates a label `a`; the substitute finds a pipe `|`, some spaces, some digits, a space, and some trailing material which doesn't include a pipe; and inserts a pipe in the middle.  The `t a` jumps back to the label if a substitution was done.

With that in place, it becomes easy to manage `awk` with a field separator of `|`.
This is verbose, but seems to do the trick:

```
awk -F '|' '
$1 > 0 { printf "%5d  %4d  %3d  %3d\n", $1, $2, $3, $4
         for (i = 5; i <= NF; i += 2) { printf "%5s  %4s  %3d  %3d\n", "", "", $i, $(i+1) }
         next
       }
$2 > 0 { printf "%5s  %4d  %3d  %3d\n", "", $2, $3, $4
         for (i = 5; i <= NF; i += 2) { printf "%5s  %4s  %3d  %3d\n", "", "", $i, $(i+1) }
         next
       }
       { for (i = 3; i <= NF; i += 2) { printf "%5s  %4s  %3d  %3d\n", "", "", $i, $(i+1) }
         next
       }'
```

Output:

```
    1  1000    0  100
              10  200
              20  300
              30  400
              40  500
              50  600
              60  700
              70  800
       1010    0  101
              10  201
              20  301
              30  401
              40  501
              50  601
    2  1000    0  110
              15  210
              25  310
              35  410
              45  510
              55  610
              65  710
       1010    0  150
              10  250
              20  350
              30  450
              40  550
```

If you need to remove the headings, add `1d;` to the start of the `sed` script.

Comment: You definitely get a bonus for both `sed` and `awk` solutions... but `0    0` looks suspicious.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, you're awsome and thank you very much for your advice and answer. We will try these code to see whether it can solve the real problem.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Good spot on the `0 0` — the problem was partly some trailing blanks, and partly not starting at field 3 in the 'nothing in column 1 or column 2' lines (starting at field 5 effectively skipped the first values).  I think the output is now correct — as expected.  (When I take what my code produces, and what is listed in the question, and run `diff -b` on the two files, I get no output, so there is no significant difference.  Phew!)

Comment: Yes, this was one that will leave you scratching your head in a couple of different directions, I had to go add more loops to make bash match the posted output format. (selfishly -- it was kinda fun...)

Comment: This gonna take some time. I will let you know once I have successfully crack it.

Comment: This works very well too, but it is quite difficult and time consuming because it doesn't use the original input. Thank you very much, I can use these script on my other problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1d;s/^(.{11}).{11}/&\n\1/;s/^((.{5}).*\n)\2/\1     /;s/^(.{5}(.{6}).*\n.{5})\2/\1      /;/\S/P;D' file
```

Delete the first line (if the header is needed see below). The key fields occupy the first 11 (the first key is 5 characters and the second 6) characters and the data fields occupy the next 11. Insert a newline and the key fields before each pair of data fields. Compare the keys on adjacent lines and replace by spaces if they are duplicated. Do not print any blank lines.

If the header is needed, use the following:

```
sed -r '1{s/\[[^]]+\]\s*//5g;y/[]/  /;s/1/n/3g;s/B/ B/;G;b};s/^(.{11}).{11}/&\n\1/;s/^((.{5}).*\n)\2/\1     /;s/^(.{5}(.{6}).*\n.{5})\2/\1      /;/\S/P;D' file
```

This does additional formatting on the first line to remove superfluous headings, `[]`'s, replace `1`'s by `n`, add an additional space for alignment and a following empty line.

Further more. By utilising the second line of the input file as a template for the data, a sed script can be created that does not have any `hard coded` values:

```
sed -r '2!d;s/\s*\S*//3g;s/.\>/&\n/;h;s/[^\n]/./g;G;s/[^\n.]/ /g;s#(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)#1d;s/^(\1\2)\1\2/\&\\n\\1/;s/^((\1).*\\n)\\2/\\1\3/;s/^(\1(\2).*\\n\1)\\2/\\1\4/;/\\S/P;D#' file |
sed -r -f - file
```

The script created from the template is piped into a second invocation of the sed as a file and run against the original file to produce the required output.

Likewise the headers may be formatted if need be as so:

```
sed -r '2!d;s/\s*\S*//3g;s/.\>/&\n/;h;s/[^\n]/./g;G;s/[^\n.]/ /g;s#(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)#s/^(\1\2)\1\2/\&\\n\\1/;s/^((\1).*\\n)\\2/\\1\3/;s/^(\1(\2).*\\n\1)\\2/\\1\4/;/\\S/P;D#' file |
sed -r -e '1{s/\[[^]]+\]\s*//5g;y/[]/  /;s/1/n/3g;s/B/ B/;G;b}' -f - file
```

By extracting the first four fields from the second line of the input file, Four variables can be made. Two regexp and two values. These variables can be used to build the sed script.

N.B. The sed script is created from strings extracted from the template and the variables produced are also strings so they can be concatenated to produce further new regexp's and new values etc etc

Comment: Hi potong. This works quite well too, but it is in simplified version. I can use these on other problem too. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Can you explain a little bit on your script?

Comment: @Amz See my added edit. For a breakdown of the first script study the crux of the solution `sed -r '1d;s/^(.{11}).{11}/&\n\1/;P;D' file`

Comment: `sed -r '2!d;s/\s*\S*//3g;s/.\>/&\n/;h;s/[^\n]/./g;G;s/[^\n.]/ /g;s#(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)#s/^(\1\2)\1\2/\&\\n\\1/;s/^((\1).*\\n)\\2/\\1\3/;s/^(\1(\2).*\\n\1)\\2/\\1\4/;/\\S/P;D#' file |
sed -r -e '1{s/\[[^]]+\]\s*//5g;y/[]/  /;s/1/n/3g;s/B/ B/;G;b}' -f - file`. Yup, that's definitely what you want to find in your code when you go back to enhance it in 6 months :-).